# How to remove array list records from other array list which is holding pojo class object

Tags: java

Hi i want to remove values from one array list to another array list where both are using model class of students and which are not in a sorted order.
Example:

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    model obj1 = new model();
    model obj2 = new model();
    model obj3 = new model();

    model obj6 = new model();
    model obj5 = new model();
    model obj4 = new model();

     obj1.setCity("pune");
     obj1.setName("aakshi");
     obj1.setSalary("22");
     obj1.setState("MH");

     obj2.setCity("pune");
     obj2.setName("aakshi");
     obj2.setSalary("23");
     obj2.setState("MH");

     obj3.setCity("pune");
     obj3.setName("aakshi");
     obj3.setSalary("24");
     obj3.setState("MH");

     obj4.setCity("pune");
     obj4.setName("aakshi");
     obj4.setSalary("22");
     obj4.setState("MH");

     obj5.setCity("pune");
     obj5.setName("aakshi");
     obj5.setSalary("23");
     obj5.setState("MH");

     obj6.setCity("pune");
     obj6.setName("aakshi");
     obj6.setSalary("24");
     obj6.setState("MH");

     ArrayList<model> List1 =new ArrayList<model>();
     ArrayList<model> list2 = new ArrayList<model>();

     List1.add(obj1);
     List1.add(obj2);
     List1.add(obj3);

     list2.add(obj4);
     list2.add(obj5);
     list2.add(obj6);

     for (model tableRow: List1) {           
         System.out.println("record to be deleted "+tableRow);
         list2.remove(tableRow);
         System.out.println("records in list"+list2);
     }       
}
```

}

Here it is not removing the element from list 1 to list 2, can anyone provide me the solution.

Comment: What are tableRowList and Datfilelist?

Comment: do u have `equals` method on `model`?

Comment: FYI: Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter and field/variable names to start with lowercase letter. Maybe you have a different convention, but `List1` / `list2` is just plain wrong!! It will confuse the heck out of anyone looking at your code.

Comment: sidgate is correct. The issue is a lack of an `equals` override. Read my answer below for an explanation.

Comment: i got your point but in my model class i have 15-20 variables and if i executing the if condition for all the attributes is time taking one and i am want to improve my performance so i looking for another alternative solution other than equals method, i need deal with 10 million records of array lists

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my previous answer. I did not understand your question. I think I understand now. You want to take all the elements in `List1` and remove their equivalencies in `list2.`

First and foremost, `List1` should be `list1` and the class `model` should be `Model` in order to follow proper Java naming conventions.

Now, as for the answer, read the documentation on the remove() method:

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

This means that, for instance, `object4` will only be removed from `list2` if `object4.equals(object1)` (at least in the case of this application). In order to ensure this works, you'll have to override the `.equals()` method in the `model` class (which should be named `Model` - again, proper naming conventions):

```
public class Model{
    private String city, name, salary, state;
    //...setters and getters

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        int result = (city != null ? city.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (salary != null ? salary.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (state != null ? state.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(!(o instanceOf Model))
            return false;
        Model oModel = (Model) o;
        if(oModel.getCity().equals(city) &&
           oModel.getName().equals(name) &&
           oModel.getSalary().equals(salary) &&
           oModel.getState().equals(state))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This override method will ensure that `.remove()` and `.removeAll()` will remove an object *o* or collection of objects from the specified list such that said list `contains(o)` (or each object in the collection to be removed). As you had it:

```
for(Model m : list1){
    list2.remove(m);
}
```

Or, a more elegant approach:

```
list2.removeAll(list1);
```

To reiterate, `remove(Object o)` and `removeAll(Collection<?> c)` remove an object or objects from a list so long as said list `.contains(o)` (or, when using `.removeAll`, `.contains((c.get(i)) in a common iteration.`

Then, it is important to know that `.contains(Object o)` returns true if and only if the specified list has an object whose `.equals(o)` returns true, as shown in the documentation for the `contains()` method:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))

In order for this to be the case, you must define (override) `.equals` in the `Model` class.

**EDIT:**

As Vladimir Vagaytsev reminded me, it is crucial that you override `hashCode` whenever overriding `equals` to ensure that `hashCode` is also a derivative of the object's relevant values for hash collections. I included said method in the above source code.

Comment: is their any other way of approach to remove records, this method is taking 0.03 seconds to remove 54 lakhs of records, as i deal with more data, can anyone provide me the better approach, it should take less time.to remove one record of arraylist

Comment: Every time you oveeride `equals()` you have to override `hashCode()` as well. See **J. Bloch's "Effective Java" 2nd edition, Item 9**

Comment: @asrithasanka Not as far as I am aware. The `remove` method is the only conventional way to remove a specific element from an `ArrayList,` and `removeAll` is the only conventional way to remove a collection. As they both check equality using `.equals,` overriding this method is, in turn, the only conventional approach. I suppose you could try using a different type of `Collection,` but I am not aware of any significant differences in performance.